# Firebase secrets - noob question, do I need to have them locally?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

We lost a dev a couple of days ago, so I ended up fixing something in a firebase function yesterday. Although, I don't yet have the environment file locally - which I assumed I only needed if I was going to run the emulators locally.

Now, we're getting an authentication error due to a missing auth token which is passed by `process.env.AUTH_KEY`.

Although, when I run `firebase functions:secrets:get 'AUTH_KEY'` I'm shown a table with "Version: 1 Enabled". So, it seems like it's set in firebase?

Am I missing something super obvious?

Comment: it is an environment variable. Look for a `.env` file in your project folder - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Comment: yes, I get that, but why should I need it locally if it's set in firebase and I never run the emulators?

Comment: Sorry - I read the link you sent, and indeed I do need them locally. Thank you so much for the answer 

Comment: Sounds like an answer @SomeoneSpecial! 